# How to query standard file's properties? Google Drive SDK

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

My goal is to check all files which are shared BY me (whetever type or permissions).

So I need to find files which I'm the owner and has Shared property set to true, so I wrote the following code:

```
  var listRequest = driveService.Files.List();
           listRequest.Q = "'me' in owners and shared = 'true'";
           FileList fileList = listRequest.Execute();
           foreach (var file in fileList.Items)
               SharedByMe.Add(file);
```

but the part with "shared = 'true'" doesn't working. I found that custom properties can be put in query, but what about standard ones? Because downloading all files and then checking it, is obviously not an option.

Comment: I don't think there is a simple solution.

Comment: So maybe a hard one? Anything that doesn't involve downloading all files and querying on client-side

Comment: I can't see any alternative to the full download.You don't say anything about your use case for me to suggest mitigations. For example, do the full scan once, store the results and the current change ID, then scan for subsequent changes.